# Div scrolling and button placement [CSS]

Tags: html, css, web

I've been fiddling with the CSS with the below code (on jsfiddle) for about 6+ hours now trying to get the right button to move proper on the page while the browser screen gets smaller - all it does is drop down and stay there no matter what I try.

Are there any bug swatters out there who can help get rid of my pest?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6ThjM/

All code from JSFiddle compiled in a single file below:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">   
var timer1;
function scrollDiv(divId, depl) {
  var scroll_container = document.getElementById(divId);
  scroll_container.scrollLeft -= depl;
  timer1 = setTimeout('scrollDiv("'+divId+'", '+depl+')', 10);
}
</script>

<div style="float:left; width: 30px">
   <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 300px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', 3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
<div id="MyDiv" style="float: left; width: 95%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden">
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 1760px;">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="height: 300px; display:inline-block;"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="height: 300px; display:inline-block;"/>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="height: 300px; display:inline-block;"/>
    <img src="img4.jpg" style="height: 300px; display:inline-block;"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width: 30px">
   <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 300px; display:inline-block;" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', -3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>

<br style="clear:both" />


<!--<div style="float:left; width: 30px">
   <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 300px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv2', 3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
<div id="MyDiv2" style="float: left; width: 960px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden">
    <div style="height: 300px; width:900px">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="height: 300px; float: left;"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="height: 300px; float: left;"/>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="height: 300px; float: right;"/>
    <img src="img4.jpg" style="height: 300px; float: right;"/>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 30px">
   <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 300px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv2', -3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We aren't a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap what you have at the moment in a div with a class of parent and give it the following style:

```
.parent {position:relative; width:100%: overflow:hidden;float:left;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ThjM/2/)

**Update**

Technically this does what you want. Use the little known `vw` view-width vale. Note that bowser support may be limited and it is a little fiddly to work with. Not only that, it breaks at quite small withds. [Media Queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) could help with this.

Change `MyDiv` to:

```
<div id="MyDiv" style="float: left; width: 82vw; height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden">
```

and `.parent` to:

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    width:90vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ThjM/7/)

Comment: Is this not static? Also it calls for horizontal scrolling on the page itself. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Can you calrify whay you want to happen to the inner content at smaller sizes? Do you want all 4 images displayed but resized or hide the overflow? Is javascript an option?

Comment: I would like the images to stay the same width and for the overflow hidden. No, the javascript is not an option. It's there to scroll through as many images in the div as are put there (may  be up to twenty). So it's basically working as a horizontal scroll through all the images. Hope that helps!

Comment: At the moment I can't think of a pure css solution. With javasctipt you could calculate and apply an absolute (ie px) width to the `.parent` element and update this value on screen resize.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JavaScript so I will look into this! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Great edit! (I know this might sound like a silly answer, but in edits doesn't JavaScript work? Just a little insight would be helpful) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I was confused as to why it wasn't working in Firefox, but it worked in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width: 5%">
    <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 300px;width:100%;"/>
</div>

<div id="MyDiv" style="float: left; width: 89%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="height: 300px;width:20%;border:1px solid #ddd;float:left;"><img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;"/></div>
    <div style="height: 300px;width:20%;border:1px solid #ddd;float:left;"><img src="img1.jpg"  style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;"/></div>
    <div style="height: 300px;width:20%;border:1px solid #ddd;float:left;"><img src="img1.jpg"  style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;"/></div>
    <div style="height: 300px;width:20%;border:1px solid #ddd;float:left;"><img src="img1.jpg"  style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;"/></div>
</div>

<div style="float:left; width: 5%">
    <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 300px; width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why are the widths of the images changing as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle with some css & html changes. check if this way you want.

```
[Fiddle link >][1]
```

***Note:*** since you have added on 4 images I've add css, only to set 4 images. you can change that by css. height of images are inheriting with parent height.